# Setting contenteditable and overwriting line-breaks to <br /> instead of <div> does not work at the end of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I've done a simple script in **[jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/et4Rk/)** that shows my problem.

I try to overwrite the line breaks in a `contenteditable=true` element from the default `<div>` to a `<br />` with the following script:

```
$(".editContents").on("keydown","[contenteditable=true]",function(e) {
    if(e.which===13) {
        lineBreak = "<br />";
        document.execCommand("insertHTML",false,lineBreak);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**It works like it should** if you press `enter` inside the text - **but as soon as** you try to make a line break at the end of the paragraph nothing happens.

Unfortunately I have no clue whats wrong with it. Any help is warmly welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is working and inserting a `<br />` at the end of the `<p>`, but whitespace at the end of `<p>` elements is truncated. You can see this by inspecting the element after you press enter at the end of the paragraph. The problem is, at the end of the `<p>`, `execCommand()` is only allowing one to be inserted. Instead of inserting, it seems to be replacing.

It does work if you add another character to `'<br />'` and insert this instead `'<br /> '` (space after the `>`), but that's probably not what you're looking for because it actually adds an extra space to your `<p>`.

You may have to check if it's the last character and use `insertAdjacentHTML()` with `beforeEnd` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input. I just tried the workaround with the space after the `<br /> ` and did not work but with `<br />&nbsp;` it works like a charm. So if I trim() the result its all what I was looking for :-) Until now I did not yet know the `insertAdjacentHTML()` method, I'll give it a try.